# For loop only increasing one of two variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted the result to show the total amount of money after adding interest every year but it only increases the year but not the amount. Why?

```
while True:
    try:
        investment = float(input('How much to invest : '))
        interest = float(input('Interest rate : '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        "Please enter a valid number"

for year in range(10):
    money = investment + (investment * interest)
    print("Total money in year {} : {}".format((year+1), money))
```

Comment: `money` is re-calcualted each iteration of the loop but never changes because `investment` and `interest` never change once defined

Comment: add a line after `money = investment + (investment * interest)` that sets `investment = money`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to accrue the interest:

```
for year in range(10):
    investment += (investment * interest)
    print("Total money in year {} : {}".format((year + 1), investment))
```

Answer (score 1):

Logical error. Your `investment` variable does not be assigned each round in the loop.